# Why does my Listview display the same value multiple times?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I've created a `Listview` to show a Static and Couple value. There can only be 
one of each displayed depending on users input in another view. Is there a better solution to this, than a `Listview`?

I've tried to bind an `Itemssource` to the `Listview` and then use `Binding Path=binding` on the textblocks which should display the values, and it does. But because there are 3 objects it displays the same value 3 times, whilst it should only display once.

This is the code from the ViewModel.

```
private async void LoadToleranceTableValues(int jobRunId)
        {
            var tolerances = await _testRunApi.GetTestRunLiveValue(jobRunId);

            if (tolerances != null)
            {
                ToleranceTable = new ObservableCollection<ToleranceTableInfo>();
                foreach (var prop in tolerances.ListBalancePlaneTolerance)
                {
                    ToleranceTable.Add(new ToleranceTableInfo
                    {
                        Name = prop.Name,
                        WeightInUnit = prop.Tolerance.ToString() + " " + prop.ToleranceUnit,
                        StaticTolerance = tolerances.StaticTolerance,
                        DynamicTolerance = tolerances.DynamicTolerance
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

And this is the listview in the Xaml

```
<ListView BorderThickness="1"
                           Grid.Row="2"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           Margin="0"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding ToleranceTable}">
                        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Static"
                                               Grid.Row="0"
                                               Grid.Column="0"
                                               MinHeight="20"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Dynamic"
                                               Grid.Row="1"
                                               Grid.Column="0"
                                               MinHeight="20"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StaticTolerance}"
                                               Grid.Column="1"
                                               TextAlignment="Right"
                                               Margin="0 0 0 0"
                                               MinHeight="20"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DynamicTolerance}"
                                               Grid.Column="1"
                                               Grid.Row="1"
                                               TextAlignment="Right"
                                               Margin="0 0 0 0"
                                               MinHeight="20"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

I want 1 of each object's to be displayed. But for the moment it displays 3 objects, all with the same values. I Figure that is because there are 3 objects in `prop`. If there is no value (or 0.0), the `Static` and `Couple` should not be displayed at all.

Comment: It is totally unclear what you are trying to achieve here. If there are 3 elements in ToleranceTable, the ListView will *obviously* show 3 items. No matter whether all of them have the same property values or not. You might also try to explain what your understanding of Static, Dynamic and Couple is and how these terms are related to the data in a ToleranceTableInfo.

Answer (score 0):

If this view is ReadOnly, simply check if the value is already present before insertion.

```
if(ToleranceTable.Count(el => el.Name == prop.Name) == 0){
 ToleranceTable.Add(...)
}
```

Anyway, the problem is not with the ListView. Any control in WPF shows exactly what it is present into the ItemsSource.
If you do not want to show Items, don't add them into the ObservableCollection, or (but I personally do not recommend this in your case), add a property in your Model and bind the itemtemplate visibility to this property.